# AngularJS: dependent asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to AngularJS, wondering What would be the correct way to handle three asynchronous requests where the parameters of the third are defined by the responses of the previous two.

```
two addresses are passed to this function
$scope.getRoutes = function(origin, destination) {

//1.A request is made to get the coordinates of the first address
dataFactory.geocode(origin)
.success(function(data) {
  $scope.originObj = data;
})
.error(function () {
});

//2.Same for the second address
dataFactory.geocode(destination)
.success(function(data) {
  $scope.destinationObj = data;
})
.error(function () {
});

//3.Finally a request for transport routes between the two sets of coordinates
dataFactory.getRoutes($scope.originObj.coordinates, $scope.destinationObj.coordinates)
.success(function(data) {
  $scope.routes = data;
})
.error(function () {
});
};
```

This gives me the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'coordinates' of undefined

Nesting the requests in the success functions functions, but is there a better way to have the last request wait around for the other two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the ability to chain promises. "Once you receive the data from this one, call this one" is the general format. Angular takes advantage of the $q library. You can find documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).